# Texture border flood fill efficiency

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, paint, flood-fill

I have a problem, I am trying to paint in regions of a `2048x2048` image and the largest areas around `1000x1000` of empty space take up around 1 second on PC. Since I am targeting mobile, this is unacceptable.

Here is the code that I have at the moment, could anyone suggest a way to make it faster?

```
public static void FloodFillBorderFromOriginalTexture(this Texture2D aTex, Texture2D refTex, int aX, int aY, Color aFillColor, Color aBorderColor)
{
    // Get the dimensions
    int w = aTex.width;
    int h = aTex.height;


    // Get the colors
    var colors = aTex.GetPixels32(); // <-- Gets the colors from the texture
    var refColors = refTex.GetPixels32();

    byte[] checkedPixels = new byte[colors.Length];

    // Assign the reference color the border color to look for
    Color refCol = aBorderColor;

    // Get the list of nodes to loop through as going along
    Queue<Point> nodes = new Queue<Point>();
    nodes.Enqueue(new Point(aX, aY));
    while (nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        // Get the point
        Point current = nodes.Dequeue();

        // Loop through to the right
        for (int i = current.x; i < w; i++)
        {
            // If we checked this pixel or its the border, skip it
            if (checkedPixels[i + current.y * w] > 0 || isBorder(colors[i + current.y * w], refCol))
                break;

            // Need to get the grayscale and multiply by it
            colors[i + current.y * w] = (Color32)((Color)refColors[i + current.y * w] * aFillColor); // <-- *** IMPORTANT! ***

            // Set the pixel as checked
            checkedPixels[i + current.y * w] = 1;

            // If we are less than height
            if (current.y + 1 < h)
            {
                // Check if the upper has not been colored and is not the border
                if (checkedPixels[i + current.y * w + w] == 0 && isNotBorder(colors[i + current.y * w + w], refCol))
                    // Add it to the stack
                    nodes.Enqueue(new Point(i, current.y + 1));
            }
            // If we are going down and not at the bottom
            if (current.y - 1 >= 0)
            {
                // Check if it is not the border and has not been checked yet
                if (checkedPixels[i + current.y * w - w] == 0 && isNotBorder(colors[i + current.y * w - w], refCol))
                    // add it to the stack
                    nodes.Enqueue(new Point(i, current.y - 1));
            }
        }

        // Loop through vertically
        for (int i = current.x - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            // Check if it has been colored and is border, break
            if (checkedPixels[i + current.y * w] > 0 || isBorder(colors[i + current.y * w], refCol))
                break;

            // Grayscale it
            colors[i + current.y * w] = (Color32)((Color)refColors[i + current.y * w] * aFillColor); // <-- *** IMPORTANT! ***

            // Set as colored
            checkedPixels[i + current.y * w] = 1;
            if (current.y + 1 < h)
            {
                // Check the next move
                if (checkedPixels[i + current.y * w + w] == 0 && isNotBorder(colors[i + current.y * w + w], refCol))
                    nodes.Enqueue(new Point(i, current.y + 1));
            }
            if (current.y - 1 >= 0)
            {
                // Check the next move
                if (checkedPixels[i + current.y * w - w] == 0 && isNotBorder(colors[i + current.y * w - w], refCol))
                    nodes.Enqueue(new Point(i, current.y - 1));
            }
        }
    }

    // Set the pixels to the modifyable texture
    aTex.SetPixels32(colors);

}

private static bool isNotBorder(Color color, Color borderColor)
{
    return color.grayscale > 0.5f;
}

private static bool isBorder(Color color, Color borderColor)
{
    return color.grayscale <= 0.5f;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, you are dynamically building a PNG ??  do you mind if I ask what for, so as to understand the question better.  it's not something you normally do in a game engine

Comment: I am trying to make a coloring book game. Basically yes, I am trying to paint  a copy of the image within borders at certain points.

Comment: If your code works then you should consider posting it on CodeReview.SE instead of StackOverflow.SE. However, I've looked into the issue of processing time it takes to alter a texture and reapply it and the fastest way that I found was to extract all pixels at once (GetPixels) then alter them with whatever method you use. Then set them all at once (SetPixels). I then set the texture as dirty and checked for dirty in the LateUpdate method. If it's dirty then I set it to clean and apply the texture. Good luck!